# How to interpret a VAR model without sigificant coefficients?

Tags: r, var, coefficients, significance, interpretation

I am trying to investigate the relationship between some Google Trends Data and Stock Prices.

I performed the augmented ADF Test and KPSS test to make sure that both time series are integrated of the same order (`I(1)`).

However, after I took the first differences, the ACF plot was completely insigificant (except for 1 of course), which told me that the differenced series are behaving like white noise.

Nevertheless I tried to estimate a VAR model which you can see attached.

As you can see, only one constant is significant. I have already read that because `Stocks.ts.l1` is not significant in the equation for GoogleTrends and `GoogleTrends.ts.l1` is not significant in the equation for Stocks, there is no dynamic between the two time series and both can also be models independently from each other with a `AR(p)` model.

I checked the residuals of the model. They fulfill the assumptions (normally distributed residuals are not totally given but ok, there is homoscedasticity, its stable and there is no autocorrelation).

But what does it mean if no coefficient is significant as in the case of the `Stocks.ts` equation? Is the model just inappropriate to fit the data, because the data doesn't follow an AR process. Or is the model just so bad, that a constant would describe the data better than the model? Or a combination of the previous questions? Any suggestions how I could proceed my analysis?

Thanks in advance

[image: VAR output (from R)]

Comment: This question would likely be more appropriate on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you have questions about the interpretations of statistical models, you will get better help asking the statisticians over at [stats.se]. This is not a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the quick advice (y)